# Why is Trump calling for OPEC to lower oil prices?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, opec

Donald Trump just called for OPEC to lower oil prices:

> We protect the countries of the Middle East, they would not be safe for very long without us, and yet they continue to push for higher and higher oil prices! We will remember. The OPEC monopoly must get prices down now!
>
> —Donald Trump [via Twitter](https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump/status/1042733544466989057) (2018-09-20)

Well, oil-rich countries do pay billions for purchasing F-15, F-16, Patriots, and so on. They also support Petrodollar system. Apparently, the USA is actually protecting its superpower status by protecting Persian Gulf countries.

So, why is Trump calling for OPEC to lower oil prices?

Comment: Is the question, "What is the basis of Trump's claim that the USA protects the OPEC nations?"  If so, that could be answered with [Kuwait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_War).

Comment: @Brythan, [What was the USA's expense?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_War#Cost). Only $9bn as opposed to trillions of dollars of Oil business let alone the secured supply of oil to the mainland USA.

Comment: That sounds a bit like a Mafia threat - "Nice oil pumps you have there, would be a pity if something happened to them ..."

Comment: Trump also [called OPEC a monopoly](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-oil-opec-trump/trump-says-opec-monopoly-must-get-prices-down-idUSKCN1M01P8) to further justify his claim. This if of course a bit silly given that the US is probably the largest oil producer this year, according to [its own gov't data](https://www.eia.gov/todayinenergy/detail.php?id=37053). So this is justified like many other things in the Trump universe: by [alternative facts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_facts).

Comment: @Fizz You can be the single largest producer and still be dwarfed by a group of slightly smaller producers. OPEC certainly behaves more like a traditional cartel than a monopoly (which still would be illegal in modern societies), and I too find it hard to argue that 40% is a monopoly.

Comment: Because Trump thinks other people should willingly give up their profits, because they're not him.

Comment: @userLTK It's not just Trump. Most people believe that cartels are harmful and should be illegal. OPEC openly engages in price fixing and artificially limiting supply. Were they companies and not states, they'd face antitrust actions in most countries on earth.

Comment: @janh: yes and no. If you want lower tariffs any EU country you also have to negotiate with the cartel that is the EU. US case law has [rejected the idea that the notion of cartels applies to governments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OPEC#International_cartel). On the other hand there's a [state cartel theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_cartel_theory) which specifically mentions the conception of the EC/EU.

Comment: @Fizz there is no price fixing in the EU, unless you consider tariffs, regulation or taxation as price fixing. Companies, and countries, within the EU do compete with each other, and varying prices are a result (but if you find out where I can buy a new Porsche for the same price as a Skoda, let me know) . As for the legal status: it's not that it does not apply, it's that foreign governments cannot be sued/prosecuted for it.

Comment: @janh: yes, that's a form of affecting prices, just like limiting production (OPEC doesn't do much else). And the biggest cartel ever is the UN when it embargoes a country. (All this under the state cartel theory.)

Comment: @Fizz: Taxation and regulation affects prices, but it does not fix them. Any company is allowed to say "well, then we won't make any profits, but we'll win market share". That's a totally different issue, don't conflate the two.

Comment: @janh: In Germany, part of the EU, there are several examples of price fixing (unless I misunderstand the term): Tobacco, books, behind-the-counter-drugs (see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preisbindung#Ausnahmen_vom_Verbot_der_Preisbindung). Also, of course there _is_ price fixing, but it _is unlawful_ in general and happens behind closed doors.

Comment: @SebastianMach Those are internal things, however - they affect every company the same and don't affect companies outside Germany. They'd be comparable to a world wide fixed price mandated by the UN, they don't create advantages for German exports. Also, tobacco isn't fixed (it's just heavily taxed, as is alcohol or fuel), and books aren't done on an industry level, but by the individual publisher for his books only, but that's another issue.

Comment: @janh: Yes. I think the term "fixing" has a double duty. It also translates into the meaning of "the merchant is not allowed to change the price". E.g., Kwik-E-Mart in Germany would not be allowed to sell Laramie cigarettes at a different price than Sprawl Mart.

Comment: @SebastianMach Yeah, it's ambiguous, but in cartel context it's about "competitors" deciding not to compete any longer but instead cooperate to increase profits by removing/reducing competition (which lowers prices and profits), so they act as if they were different brands of the same monopolist.

Comment: Well today's market action makes this a big case of: Be careful what you wish for!

Answer (score 8):

Because he wants the USA to pay less for the oil it buys.
The reason he is doing it in this manner is probably two-fold:

1. He has a background in large business where it is common to put the squeeze on your suppliers
2. He is not diplomatic at all (to put it diplomatically), as his myriad tantrums have shown.
   This explains why he has chosen the demand-and-threaten model.

Why OPEC? This is because it's the body which decides on output, and price directly to a certain extent. It's a cartel, and as such pretty much can force the price up or down.

As to whether cheap prices are really good for the US is a different question- self-sufficiency driven by higher prices and an acceleration to alternative technologies may very well be better for the economy in the long run.

Comment: OPEC prices have a large influence on the general oil price, so "squeezing your supplier" means the prices you sell at will also suffer - the US aren't solely on the demand side, and the main supplier to the US appears to be Canada, not OPEC countries ([albeit the margin is small](https://www.eia.gov/energyexplained/index.php?page=oil_imports)).

Comment: @jahn, indeed my comments at the end re self sufficiency is in relation to US domestic production, although I did not make your excellent point explicitly.

Comment: Reason C - His ego can not handle people pointing out gas prices were lower under Obama (regardless of whether presidents have any meaningful impact over that, or whether the higher prices generally are an indication of a robust economy).

Comment: @PoloHoleSet As opposed to Obama stating that he would prefer the price to be $4.00. Trump wants lower prices at the pump, that bastard.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I would also guess he's trying to get *anything* positive to happen with the stock market going the way it is and Covid-19 looming over his head

Comment: The US is a net oil producer. A lower price means shale oil cannot compete so we will now become an importer, also the shale oil jobs will disappear, which is bad for the economy not good.